# No Input File Specified for Wordpress on Local Virtualbox Centos 7 VM running NGINX

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, virtualbox, centos7

I am trying to use pretty permalinks on my local `Wordpress` site on `Centos 7`

But when I try to go to a post I get `No file specified`

I do have this site in a shared folder but even when I put it on a regular folder on my VM it does not work.

I have looked all over for an answer but have not found one.

Here is my `nginx configuration file`

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

# note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
root   /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Comment: The error implies that `/var/www/html/index.php` does not exist. What is the URL of your WordPress site? Is there a missing sub-directory?

Comment: Damn!! I Duh, putting the `index.php` worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to move the `index.php` to my root web directory.

Comment: Moving `index.php` in a WordPress installation should not be necessary. Your `try_files` statement should point to the actual URI of WordPress's top level `index.php` file, e.g. `try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;`